# iOS: Control the native Clock App from Another App

Tags: ios

Is it possible to control the native Clock app from my app?

Is it for instance possible to start its timer, or disable and enable an alarm? I want my app to start up, do a modification, and then die.

If it's possible, where do I find more info about this?

This will be my first app. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure it isn't doable within public APIs, and i would be very surprised if it was doable at all. What are you trying to do?